# where is my application folder in android?

Tags: android, file, filesystems

My application records some data from a sensor of my phone, and it store the data to a file in the application's directory.

I run my application under the debug mode. And I was trying to find the application's folder and open the file with the saved data. However, I was not able to even find the app's folder.In the log information, it said the app's location is

```
" '/data/app/myAppPackage.apk' (success) ---"
```

but I can not find it anywhere by browsing the phone's disk.

Any hints?

thx in advance

Comment: Try to find the folder looking for the application package name. Something like `/data/data/com.package.name`

Comment: @RicardoA.HermosillaCarrillo: this directory works in the emulator but the device

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir() should return path to app's internal folder, and I believe that folder exists on any Android device. Have you tried it on that device? Standard path for the app folder is /data/data/<package_name>, as Ricardo mentioned above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding you will not be able to view this data on the mobile device. When you test the app in eclipse you will be able to see in the applications folder the new data sets, But on your phone, it is encapsulated by the APK.

Try saving the values to sd card?

Comment: thx, this works! I saved it into the external storage and found what I need :-)